# ERROR: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Maximum attribute size limit (524288) exceeded

Tags: java, xml, spring, weblogic

I am trying to mount an OMElement type object with an XML where I add a large document. And I get the following error:

**ERROR: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Maximum attribute size limit (524288) exceeded**

I've been looking for a way to increase that attribute size limit but I don't know where to apply that change. The line of code where it gives me the error is the following:

`OMElement myOMElement = AXIOMUtil.stringToOM(marshall(Data.class, data)); env = TransportUtils.createSOAPEnvelope(myOMElement);`

Comment: Maybe this link is helpful: https://github.com/ngallagher/simplexml/issues/36